# python mock get calling object

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I have a `UUT` class which instantiates `Worker` objects, and calls their `do_stuff()` method.
The `Worker` objects uses a `Provider` object for two things:

1. Calls methods on the provider object to do some stuff
2. Gets notifications from the provider by subscribing a method with the provider's events

When a worker gets a notification, it processes it, an notifies the `UUT` object, which in reponse can create more `Worker` objects.

I've already tested each class on its own, and I want to test `UUT`+`Worker` together. For that, I intend to mock-out `Provider`.

```
import mock
import unittest
import provider

class Worker():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        resource.default_resource.subscribe('on_spam', self._on_spam) # I'm going to patch 'resource.default_resource'

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.resource.do_stuff()

    def _on_spam(self, message):
        self._tell_uut_to_create_more_workers(message['num_of_new_workers_to_create'])


class UUT():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._workers = []

    def gen_worker_and_do_stuff(self, *args)
       worker = Worker(*args)
       self._workers.append(resource)
       worker.do_stuff()


class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('resource.default_resource', spec_set=resource.Resource)
    def test_1(self, mock_resource):
        uut = UUT()
        uut.gen_worker_and_do_stuff('Egg')   # <-- say I automagically grabbed the resulting Worker into self.workers
        self.workers[0]._on_spam({'num_of_new_workers_to_create':5}) # <-- I also want to get hold of the newly-created workers
```

Is there a way to grab the worker objects generated by `uut`, without directly accessing the `_workers` list in `uut` (which is an implementation detail)?

I guess I can do it in `Worker.__init__`, where the worker subscribes to provider events, so I guess the question reduces to:
How to I extract the `self` in the callee, when calling `resource.default_resource.subscribe('on_spam', self._on_spam)`?

Comment: What you want is not possible. Change your API if it is not testable.

Comment: Or you can patch the `Worker` class instead.

Comment: @ms4py - I did patch the `Worker` class at the unit test stage. Now I'm doing integration tests, and I want to see the entire stack working together

Comment: @bavaza What exactly aspect of this code do you want to test?

Comment: @bavaza So it seems, you want to test two aspects: 1) Worker sends its notifications, 2) UUT handles those notification properly. So, test them independently, not all at once. But, I think, more code is needed for the full picture.

Comment: @bereal - I revised the question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score -1):

As an application of the Dependency Inversion principle, I'd pass the `Worker` class as a dependency to `UUT`:

```
class UUT():
    def __init__(self, make_worker=Worker):
        self._workers = []
        self._make_worker = make_worker

    def gen_worker_and_connect(self, *args)
       worker = self._make_worker(*args)
       self._workers.append(resource)
       worker.connect()
```

Then provide anything you want from the test instead of `Worker`. This own function could share the created object with the test scope. Besides solving this particular problem, that would also make the dependency explicit and independent of the `UUT` implementation. And you would not need to mock the resource thing as well, which makes the test dependent on things unrelated to the class under test.

Comment: You can achieve the same by patching the Worker class directly. I wouldn't suggest a factory function in Python.

Comment: @bereal - injection is not possible in my case - please see the clarification I added.

Comment: @ms4py It depends on the methodology used. In TDD, DI is always preferable over any kind of patching since (in brief) tests are not supposed to be aware of the implementation, so patching is a design smell. In non-TDD... well, as a TDD fanboy I won't touch that topic with a long stick.